# Using a 'for loop', run a script on all files in a directory

Tags: shell-script, files

I have a script I wish to run through a directory of files:

```
awk '{if(NR%4==1) {printf(">%s\n",substr($0,2));} else if(NR%4==2) print;}' < TNGA_C_0hr_Joined_Asz1.fastqsanger | awk 'NR%2==0' | sed 's/TGAGATGTGA/*/p'  | cut -d '*' -f 2 -s | sort -k 1.180,1.194 -u | cat -n | sed 's/^/>/' | tr "[\t]" "\n" > TNGA_C_0hr_Asz1_Collapsed.fasta
```

I have tested this script, and it works fine for what I need it to do.

What I want to do is create a for loop that will apply it to all the files in a directory. I've tried the below, and it did not work. Variations of it have also been tried.

```
for filename in /Test/*.fastqsanger; do
    awk '{if(NR%4==1) {printf(">%s\n",substr($0,2));} else if(NR%4==2) print;}' < filename.fastqsanger | awk 'NR%2==0' | sed 's/TGAGATGTGA/*/p'  | cut -d '*' -f 2 -s | sort -k 1.180,1.194 -u | cat -n | sed 's/^/>/' | tr "[\t]" "\n" > filename.fasta
done
```

I'm fairly new to programming so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't your script be using `$filename` instead of `filename.fastqsanger`?  By the way, when you get an error message, you should give the exact message to make the error more obvious.

Comment: Thanks Julie, that hint was all I needed to crack it. Here's the modified script:for filename in *.fastqsanger; do      awk '{if(NR%4==1) {printf(">%s\n",substr($0,2));} else if(NR%4==2) print;}' < $filename | awk 'NR%2==0' | sed 's/TGAGATGTGA/*/p'  | cut -d '*' -f 2 -s | sort -k 1.180,1.194 -u | cat -n | sed 's/^/>/' | tr "[\t]" "\n" > $filename.fasta; done

Comment: The output at the end would be `TNGA_C_0hr_Joined_Asz1.fastqsanger.fasta`. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Your script is not using the loop's `filename` variable.  `filename.fastqsanger` does not refer to a variable and implies that the full filename is not already present although it is.

Here is the corrected version:

```
for filename in /Test/*.fastqsanger; do
    awk '{if(NR%4==1) {printf(">%s\n",substr($0,2));} else if(NR%4==2) print;}' < $filename | awk 'NR%2==0' | sed 's/TGAGATGTGA/*/p'  | cut -d '*' -f 2 -s | sort -k 1.180,1.194 -u | cat -n | sed 's/^/>/' | tr "[\t]" "\n" > $filename.fasta
done
```

Answer (score -1):

You are not using the `filename` variable in the line below:

```
for filename in /Test/*.fastqsanger; do
    awk '{if(NR%4==1) {printf(">%s\n",substr($0,2));} else if(NR%4==2) print;}' < filename.fastqsanger | awk 'NR%2==0' | sed 's/TGAGATGTGA/*/p'  | cut -d '*' -f 2 -s | sort -k 1.180,1.194 -u | cat -n | sed 's/^/>/' | tr "[\t]" "\n" > filename.fasta
done
```

Try:

```
for filename in /Test/*.fastqsanger
do
    fname=`basename $filename .fastqsanger`
    awk '{if(NR%4==1) {printf(">%s\n",substr($0,2));} else if(NR%4==2) print;}' < $filename | awk 'NR%2==0' | sed 's/TGAGATGTGA/*/p'  | cut -d '*' -f 2 -s | sort -k 1.180,1.194 -u | cat -n | sed 's/^/>/' | tr "[\t]" "\n" > $fname.fasta
done
```

This saves the basename of the file in `$fname` so that:

`/Test/abcd.fastqsanger` becomes `/Test/abcd.fasta` instead of `/Test/abcd.fastqsanger.fasta`